# updating the MYSQL database from JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have been trying this for a while now and when i click the update button it says 'details saved successfully'  and updates nothing. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

below is my code for edit button on `JTable`:

```
private void jButtonEditEmployeeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

     try {
         //int emp_id= jTable1.getSelectedRow();
         //  String tableClick=(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(emp_id,2).toString());
         //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_certificate", "root", "");
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
         String sql = "UPDATE  certificate SET Cert_Name=?, Vendor=?, Cert_Code=? ";
         PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();

         for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

             String Cert_Name = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 4);
             String Vendor = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 5);
             String Cert_Code = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6);

             pstmt.setString(1, Cert_Name);
             pstmt.setString(2, Vendor);
             pstmt.setString(3, Cert_Code);
             //pstmt.setString(4, tableClick);

             pstmt.addBatch();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Details edited successfully");
         }
         pstmt.executeBatch();
         con.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Details not edited");
     }

 }
```

Comment: Please format your code for better readability.

Comment: Do remember to close all the resources ( Connections, PreparedStatements) in a finally block

Comment: Have you debugged this, and if so, how? Have you at least printed out the Strings being submitted to the prepared statement? If so, are you seeing the Strings that you expected to see?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels please tell me how to do debug and print out strings. I am new in coding.

Comment: For example, call: `System.out.println("cert name: " + Cert_Name);` right after creating the Cert_Name variable (although it should be called certName to comply with Java naming standards).

Comment: Same for the other Strings....

Answer (score 0):

You need where condition...

```
"UPDATE  certificate SET Cert_Name=?, Vendor=?, Cert_Code=? where..."
```

but there is always the last value

Comment: still does nothing.could you be having a similar code example?Thank you